# Python skipping 'zero' values when plotting a series

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a plot which summarizes data by location. The script reads in 10+ government files and plots them correctly.  The issue I'm having is that if one of that stations does not contain data for one of the x-axis parameters it plots this as a '0'.  This is correct, but I would like to skip plotting this bar, but don't want to remove the station.

For example, in the following graph I don't want to display 'Kitchener' data for NO2 as no data was recorded. Is there any way to do this?  I have each station as a list with 12 values (one for each pollutant) and am graphing each series.  Python 3.3[image]

Thanks.
*Disclaimer: this is falsified data, don't freak out about VOC's in Kitchener*

The code I'm using to plot iterates through the following for each station included in the data set is below.  The 'graph_data' variable is a set of lists, one for each station containing 12 values where any pollution not measured at a station contains a '0'.

`rects1 = plt.bar(index, graph_data[0], bar_width, color = '#EDF062', label = stations[0], align='center')`

Comment: I can't find `'Kitchener' data for NO2` on you plot. What exactly part of it you want to hide?

Comment: Looks like you are plotting the data as a bar graph using `matplotlib`, it will be easier to provide you an answer if you post the code that generates the plot.

Comment: @alko, that's the point.  The kitchener data is on there, but it's '0' so you get a blank space.  I would like the Brampton and North Bay bars to be touching when the data in between is '0'.